# Imacros, search source

Tags: imacros

I am not expert on imacros search source command, I tried to looking some text on the source page to be extracted..

```
<div id='keywordsDiv' name='keywordsDiv' class='r-sidebar'>
            <dl class="list normal-text">
                       <dt class="key">Category</dt>
         <dd class="value"><a class="black" href="http://www.abcd">abcd</a>                 &nbsp;</dd>
                     <dt class="key">Style</dt>
         <dd class="value"><a class="black" href="http://www.def.com/">def</a>&nbsp;</dd>
                     <dt class="key">Location</dt>
    <dd class="value"><a class="black" href="http://www.ghi.com/">GHI</a>&nbsp;</dd>
                             <dt class="key">Keywords</dt>
              <dd class="value">
   </dd>
           </dl>
                </div>
```

How can I extract from source a text from div id=keywordsDiv.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:keywordsDiv EXTRACT=TXT
```

Try this.

Comment: it's not working, the keywordsdiv only visible on source page, it's not showing at actual page. do you have another solutions? thanks

Comment: Show me the page and I will try it.

Comment: may I send you the page thru email?

Answer (score 2):

I've used the SEARCH command. It uses regex and has worked well for me searching source code. It can really be powerful in automating dynamic pages.

Here is a link:
http://wiki.imacros.net/SEARCH

*Note: I've run into issues with complex regex, I think there are a few flavors or regex and iMacros uses a specific one, plus there are regex limitations.